# Bootstrap 5 card overlapping in smaller screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

```css
.footerlink a{
    color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}
.card{
    height:18rem;
}
.bd-placeholder-img {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    text-anchor: middle;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
      font-size: 3.5rem;
    }
  }
.thumbcard{
width: 15rem;
height: 18rem;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
.thumbcard{
width: 10rem;
height: 18rem;
}
}

a.custom-card,
a.custom-card:hover {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}
@media(max-width: 768px){
a.custom-card h5{
font-size: 1rem;
}
a.custom-card .card-body{
padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
font-size: 0.95rem;
line-height: none;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.79.0">
    <title>Album example · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/album/">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style7.css">

    
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="flex-row d-flex">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="Brand">Brand</a>
        </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDarkDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDarkDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav Item</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">                
                  </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

<main>


  <div class="album py-5 bg-light">
    <!-- <h2>Latest Articles</h2> -->
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Recent Articles</h2>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-3 row-cols-md-4 g-3">
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr/>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Adventure</h2>
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-3 row-cols-md-4 g-3">
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-6">
            <a href="#" class="custom-card">
          <div class="card shadow-sm thumbcard">
            <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>

            <div class="card-body">
                <h5>This is demo header</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is demo test. This is another demo text. This is demo text</p>              
            </div>
            <!-- <div class="card-footer">Card Footer only as Headline. Anohter paragraph added to test content</div> -->
          </div>
          </a>
        </div> 

      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</main>

<footer class="text-muted py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- <p class="float-end mb-1">
      <a href="#">Back to top</a>
    </p> -->
    <p class="justify-content-center ms-5">©Website is affiliated to Third Party Websites</p>
    <!-- <p class="mb-4 ms-5">Album example is &copy; Bootstrap, but please download and customize it for yourself!</p> -->
    <!-- <p class="mb-0">New to Bootstrap? <a href="/">Visit the homepage</a> or read our <a href="../getting-started/introduction/">getting started guide</a>.</p> -->
    <div class="footerlink"><h4>
        <span><a href="#" class="px-4">About</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="px-4">Contact</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="px-4">Disclaimer</a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="px-6"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="#3b5998" class="bi bi-facebook" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M16 8.049c0-4.446-3.582-8.05-8-8.05C3.58 0-.002 3.603-.002 8.05c0 4.017 2.926 7.347 6.75 7.951v-5.625h-2.03V8.05H6.75V6.275c0-2.017 1.195-3.131 3.022-3.131.876 0 1.791.157 1.791.157v1.98h-1.009c-.993 0-1.303.621-1.303 1.258v1.51h2.218l-.354 2.326H9.25V16c3.824-.604 6.75-3.934 6.75-7.951z"/></svg></a></span>        
        <span><a href="#" class="px-4"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="#bc2a8d" class="bi bi-instagram" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M8 0C5.829 0 5.556.01 4.703.048 3.85.088 3.269.222 2.76.42a3.917 3.917 0 0 0-1.417.923A3.927 3.927 0 0 0 .42 2.76C.222 3.268.087 3.85.048 4.7.01 5.555 0 5.827 0 8.001c0 2.172.01 2.444.048 3.297.04.852.174 1.433.372 1.942.205.526.478.972.923 1.417.444.445.89.719 1.416.923.51.198 1.09.333 1.942.372C5.555 15.99 5.827 16 8 16s2.444-.01 3.298-.048c.851-.04 1.434-.174 1.943-.372a3.916 3.916 0 0 0 1.416-.923c.445-.445.718-.891.923-1.417.197-.509.332-1.09.372-1.942C15.99 10.445 16 10.173 16 8s-.01-2.445-.048-3.299c-.04-.851-.175-1.433-.372-1.941a3.926 3.926 0 0 0-.923-1.417A3.911 3.911 0 0 0 13.24.42c-.51-.198-1.092-.333-1.943-.372C10.443.01 10.172 0 7.998 0h.003zm-.717 1.442h.718c2.136 0 2.389.007 3.232.046.78.035 1.204.166 1.486.275.373.145.64.319.92.599.28.28.453.546.598.92.11.281.24.705.275 1.485.039.843.047 1.096.047 3.231s-.008 2.389-.047 3.232c-.035.78-.166 1.203-.275 1.485a2.47 2.47 0 0 1-.599.919c-.28.28-.546.453-.92.598-.28.11-.704.24-1.485.276-.843.038-1.096.047-3.232.047s-2.39-.009-3.233-.047c-.78-.036-1.203-.166-1.485-.276a2.478 2.478 0 0 1-.92-.598 2.48 2.48 0 0 1-.6-.92c-.109-.281-.24-.705-.275-1.485-.038-.843-.046-1.096-.046-3.233 0-2.136.008-2.388.046-3.231.036-.78.166-1.204.276-1.486.145-.373.319-.64.599-.92.28-.28.546-.453.92-.598.282-.11.705-.24 1.485-.276.738-.034 1.024-.044 2.515-.045v.002zm4.988 1.328a.96.96 0 1 0 0 1.92.96.96 0 0 0 0-1.92zm-4.27 1.122a4.109 4.109 0 1 0 0 8.217 4.109 4.109 0 0 0 0-8.217zm0 1.441a2.667 2.667 0 1 1 0 5.334 2.667 2.667 0 0 1 0-5.334z"/></svg></a></span>
        <span><a href="#" class="px-4"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" fill="#00acee" class="bi bi-twitter" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path d="M5.026 15c6.038 0 9.341-5.003 9.341-9.334 0-.14 0-.282-.006-.422A6.685 6.685 0 0 0 16 3.542a6.658 6.658 0 0 1-1.889.518 3.301 3.301 0 0 0 1.447-1.817 6.533 6.533 0 0 1-2.087.793A3.286 3.286 0 0 0 7.875 6.03a9.325 9.325 0 0 1-6.767-3.429 3.289 3.289 0 0 0 1.018 4.382A3.323 3.323 0 0 1 .64 6.575v.045a3.288 3.288 0 0 0 2.632 3.218 3.203 3.203 0 0 1-.865.115 3.23 3.23 0 0 1-.614-.057 3.283 3.283 0 0 0 3.067 2.277A6.588 6.588 0 0 1 .78 13.58a6.32 6.32 0 0 1-.78-.045A9.344 9.344 0 0 0 5.026 15z"/></svg></a></span>        
    </h4></div>
  </div>
  
</footer>


<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.js"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

After searching in the internet I could not find any viable solution.
Please bear with me, this is important project, and I could not find meaningful solution to this problem.

This is extended version of Bootstrap [Album](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/album/) Example.

I have added navbar, and modified and added CSS to view and better render the cards in mobile screen.

However I could not get over the issue of overlapping in small screens. When I decrease the screen in Google developer option, I could see the overlapping cards in Tablet screen and smaller(less than 968px) screen size.

I want to find the issue, and get rid of overlapping cards. [image: The overlapping cards in smaller screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `width: 100%` with `.thumbcard` classes and with `@media(max-width:768px){}` classes.

**Edited** CSS classes

```
 .thumbcard{
width: 15rem;
width: 100%;
height: 18rem;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
.thumbcard{
width: 10rem;
width: 100%;
height: 18rem;
}
}
```